# Weird error when creating a trigger in MySQL 5.6.27

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi guys I'm trying to create this simple trigger in one of my database's table but for some reason I am getting this weird error. I've already searched about it but I have not found a solution to this issue. Can someone help me? THANKS.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `dataset`.`student_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE 
DELETE ON `student` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
delete from student_grades where std_id = old.student_id;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Comment: "for some reason" - the error message has already *told* you the reason.

Comment: i advice you to use InnoDB engine with foreiyn keys and `ON DELETE CASADE` instead. It does the same thing but better then the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL engine is saying that the user need more privileges than it does to execute. This is because creating some triggers that modify tables (as "delete") will be logged when executed (read more information here [Binary Logging of Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-logging.html)

One of the solutions is inside the link, in short you could execute this command before the creation of the trigger

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

But maybe you need some privileges to change a global var on MySQL.